# Second line in li starts under the bullet after CSS-reset

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems with my `ul`-list after using applying CSS-reset.

When the text in the `li` is long and it breaks to a second line, the text begins under the bullet. I'd like it to start with the same margin/padding as the text on the right side of the bullet.

Sort of hard to explain, but if you look at the example-image. The left-image is the list today. "motta varsel [...]" begins under the bullet, but I'd like it to look the picture on the right.

How can I do this with CSS? I assume there is something very simple I've overlooked, but I can't figure out what. Google searches did not return anything useful either.

[image]

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The `li` tag has a property called `list-style-position`. This makes your bullets inside or outside the list. On default, it’s set to `inside`. That makes your text wrap around it. If you set it to `outside`, the text of your `li` tags will be aligned.

The downside of that is that your bullets won't be aligned with the text outside the `ul`. If you want to align it with the other text you can use a margin.

```
ul li {
    /*
     * We want the bullets outside of the list,
     * so the text is aligned. Now the actual bullet
     * is outside of the list’s container
     */
    list-style-position: outside;

    /*
     * Because the bullet is outside of the list’s
     * container, indent the list entirely
     */
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

---

**Edit 15th of March, 2014**
Seeing people are still coming in from Google, I felt like the original answer could use some improvement

- Changed the code block to provide **just** the solution
- Changed the indentation unit to `em`’s
- Each property is applied to the `ul` element
- Good comments :)

Comment: Brilliant! I knew there was some simple way to to this. Thanks a lot! Will accept in 5 min.

Comment: This should be ul li { ... }

Comment: @jvenema Personally I prefer just `ul`, because I want to modify the list entirely, not every item. However, the spec does say all the `list-style-...` properties applies to **list items**, rather than lists. I’ll edit the answer for correctness :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It's actually good typographic practice to let the bullets sit in the gutter, so I wouldn't bother with the margin-left or repositioning the list.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is specific to the project I'm assigned, but 1em still had a few pixels "outside". However, 1rem did the trick!

Comment: To get the bullets to align with how they would be if there was no <ul> I find that I need margin-left: -1.25em

Answer (score 42):

Here is a good [example](http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2012/01/indenting-second-line-of-li-list-items.html) -

```
ul li{
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d9VNk/

Answer (score 24):

I second Dipaks' answer, but often just the text-indent is enough as you may/maynot be positioning the ul for better layout control.

```
ul li{
text-indent: -1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the fish in a `:before` style in css. Also you have a spelling mistake in your HTML. It should be `<ul>`. Font Awesome should give you the code to put into `content`.

```css
li {
      padding: 0% 0% 5% 3%; 
      width: 100%;
    list-style-position: outside;
    position: relative;
    }

    li:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        background: black;
        top: 10px;
        left: -5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col">
          
        <ul>
          <p class="col align-self-center">
          <li>5% marketing and strategic alliances</li> 
          <li>10% Metadata release (Rarity tools) Focus on community growth</li>
          <li>25% Listing in Magic Eden</li> 
          <li>50% First Donation to partners</li> 
          <li>65% Increase in marketing investment</li> 
          <li>80% Bluepaper Publication of Phase 2</li> 
          <li>100% Second Donation to partners</li> 
          </p>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Dipak's answer the best solution for me (Thanks Dipak!), however I needed to add a comma between the ul and li. List Style Type wasn't a concern for me and I only used padding-left, also 1.5em for text-indent.
My list was within multiple div's, so this might have also been a contributing factor.

```css
ul, li{
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-indent: -1.5em;
}
```