# Multiline list item that keeps the indent

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list with two items. Both items have multiline text. I'd like to make it to where the list bullet is like a "column" and the text is the next "column" over -- meaning that with multiline text, I don't want the text to wrap to underneath the bullet, but to wrap to the next line at the same indented space where the first line is at.

Just a basic list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Text that is multiline</li>
    <li>More of the same</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use a table if you want to do that

Comment: Can you give an example it would be so much easier to answer

Comment: _I don't want the text to wrap to underneath the bullet_ - Where are you seeing text end up underneath a bullet? If I just put a ul list in JSFiddle, it behaves the way you want it to.

Comment: @BSMP: Yep, you're right. The default stylings do work as I hoped they would... (facepalm) It must be some other stylings applied to uls and lis elsewhere in the app that are causing my problem. Feel free to answer with your comment or close out the question.

Comment: I actually found an SO question with the same issue and there's an answer explaining what causes it (list-style-position): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556493/2nd-line-in-li-start-under-the-bullet-after-css-reset