# Unordered list(bullet point) - indented

Tags: css

I would like to display an unordered list with urls included and indented (but all lines justified/to the left) with each other

```
* line one text text ted
  more text text
  text
* line two text ted
  more text text
  text
* line three text ted
  more text text
  text
```

I want the * (bullet point) indented but all text to start at the same position.

I have the following but its not working (text size wrong, displaying with spaces and out of line) :

```
<ul id="subvmtext">        
<li><a href ="breakfast">breakfast</a></li>
<li><a href ="breakfast">breakfast</a></li>
<li><a href ="breakfast">breakfast</a></li></ul>
```

There is other css in my file and its making my text font really small so if you could put it all inline it would be great.

**edit solution listed below is almost it

```
<ul style='list-style-position: outside'>
    <li>Outside list</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item with a <br />line break</li>
</ul>
```

But there is a bullet point showing for the second line of my text

Comment: That's the default behaviour isn't it - http://jsfiddle.net/sxzhypsr/1/ It's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: maybe its not possible to display the text inline with the bullet point ? I having trouble displaying list items in Arial, font size 18px with matching URLS

Comment: possible duplicate of [2nd line in li start under the bullet after CSS-reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556493/2nd-line-in-li-start-under-the-bullet-after-css-reset)

Comment: What do you mean by "inline with the bullet point"?  Perhaps you could show us a proper demo of the actual issue.

Answer (score 2):

The property you are looking for is [`list-style-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position). The default value is `outside`, that is what you are looking for. See the code:

```html
<ul style='list-style-position: inside'>
    <li>Inside list</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item with a <br />line break</li>
</ul>

<ul style='list-style-position: outside'>
    <li>Outside list</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item with a <br />line break</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah...I think this is what he is after.

Comment: i think that is is but i have to check that the full text in item starts inline

Comment: the second line doesnt match the text of the first line, and the bullet point is wrong.  I am looking for a black ball

Comment: @Aindriu, what do you mean, I don't understand? Please note that I've added both options (inside/ outside positioning). Please clarify....

Comment: the outside list is what I am looking for but when I put a <a href =""> after the <li> text goes small.  how do you overrule that  ? also, the bullet points are not 8 balls (all black)

Comment: its ok, i got the css font sorted... but its still diplaying the () in white

Answer (score 1):

Your other CSS is most likely interfering with indentation.  Otherwise all the lines would be justified to the left, like you want them to.  See below.

```
<div style="width:100px;">
   <ul id="subvmtext">        
     <li><a href ="breakfast">breakfast at tiffany's</a></li>
     <li><a href ="breakfast">breakfast at tiffany's</a></li>
     <li><a href ="breakfast">breakfast at tiffany's</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

If you post a jsfiddle with the rest of your CSS, I might be able to help more.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s3os0rtb/)

**CSS**

```
li:before {
    content: "* ";
}

li{
    list-style:none;
}
```