# List element space between number and text css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I will be using Unordered list elements. Here i seperating or giving some space between the bullet and text. It is working fine but when the text using another line due to some large sentence in the particular list element it is not using the space.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 56px;
}

li::before {
  content: "•";
  padding-right: 38px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Password must have Alphabet, Numeral and Special Characters.Password must have Alphabet, Numeral and Special Characters</li>
  <li>Password must have Alphabet, Numeral and Special Characters</li>
</ul>
```

Please let me know in case not able to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this link may helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11556597/4269154

Comment: Thans @SrinivasR

Answer (score 4):

put display:table in your li and li::before add display: table-cell may it  work for you

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li { 
    padding-left: 56px; 
    display: table;
}

li::before {
    content: "•"; 
    padding-right: 38px;
    color: blue; 
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Password must have Alphabet, Numeral and Special Characters.Password must have Alphabet, Numeral and Special Characters</li>
  <li>Password must have Alphabet, Numeral and Special Characters</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  content: "•";
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [list-style-type](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_list-style-type.asp)?

```css
ul.bullet {
    
    list-style-type: disc;
    
    /*
     * you can change to the style that you want
     * list-style-type: circle;
     */
}
```

```html
<ul class="bullet">
  <li>Password must have Alphabet, Numeral and Special Characters.Password must have Alphabet, Numeral and Special Characters</li>
  <li>Password must have Alphabet, Numeral and Special Characters</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `li` tag and the `li::before` with the following code:

```
li { 
    padding-left: 56px; 
    display: table;
}

li::before {
    content: "•"; 
    padding-right: 38px;
    color: blue; 
    display: table-cell;
}
```